# Correct way to represent an Enum with values of specific types

Tags: python, mypy

I'm trying to represent an Enum where each key must have a specific type for its values. For example, I have defined this:

```py
from enum import Enum, auto
from typing import Any

class MatchType(Enum):
    NATIVE = auto()
    DICTIONARY = auto()
    LIST = auto()

class MatchResult:
    type: MatchType
    value: Any

    def __init__(self, type: MatchType, value: Any):
        self.type = type
        self.value = value
```

Now how I can associate those types to a corresponding value type? What I mean, if a function returns a `MatchResult` with type = `MatchType.NATIVE` I want to Mypy check that I'm using a `float | int | string | bool` as value:

```py
def fn_returs_primitive() -> MathResult:
    ...
    return MathResult(MatchType.NATIVE, [1, 2, 3])  # This CAN NOT happen as NATIVE should be int, float, string or boolean, NOT a list
```

**How could I ensure that in Python?**

In Rust, for instance, you can define an Enum where each type has parameters:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

enum MatchType<T> {
    NATIVE(u32),
    DICTIONATY(HashMap<String, T>),
    LIST(Vec<T>)
}
```

Does something similar exist in Python? Any kind of help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python has an untagged union type called `Union`. This type is considered untagged because there is no information storing which variant of the enum is selected. For your use case, here is an untagged implementation:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Union

T = TypeVar("T")
MatchType = Union[int, dict[str, T], list[T]]

def get() -> MatchType:
    return [1, 2, 3]

def match_on(match_type: MatchType):
    if isinstance(match_type, int):
        print("An int.")
    elif isinstance(match_type, dict):
        print("A dict.")
    elif isinstance(match_type, list):
        print("A list.")
```

Notice however that we have to iterate through all possible `MatchType`s during matching. This is because there is no tag stored with the variants of an untagged union that we can index a map / table by. A naive attempt to do constant-time matching might look like this:

```
def match_on(match_type: MatchType):
    {
        int: lambda: print("An int."),
        dict: lambda: print("A dictionary."),
        list: lambda: print("A list.")
    }[type(match_type)]()
```

but given a subclass of `int`, this would throw an `IndexError` because the type isn't strictly `int`.

To enable constant time matching like the rust compiler might emit for matching on a tagged union, you'd have to mimic a tagged union like this:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import TypeVar, final, Generic, Union

T = TypeVar("T")

@final
@dataclass
class MatchNative:
    value: int

@final
@dataclass
class MatchDictionary(Generic[T]):
    value: dict[str, T]

# Avoid collision with built in type `List` by prepending `Match`.
@final
@dataclass
class MatchList(Generic[T]):
    value: list[T]

MatchType = Union[MatchNative, MatchDictionary[T], MatchList[T]]

def get():
    return MatchList([1, 2, 3])

def match_on(match_type: MatchType):
    {
        MatchNative: lambda: print("An int."),
        MatchDictionary: lambda: print("A dictionary."),
        MatchList: lambda: print("A list.")
    }[type(match_type)]()
```

The `@dataclass` annotations aren't required, it just creates a `__init__` for the tags that I then used in the `get` function.

Here, we created three classes that include the relevant data for each type, while also serving as a tag themselves because of the extra layer of indirection introduced. These classes are made `@final` in order to rule out subclasses of the tags being given as an instance of the `Union`. The `@final` annotations enable constant-time matching.

Note that both the untagged and tagged implementations are still missing exhaustiveness checking, which rust's `match` statement has. Python 3.10 is coming with a `match` statement, but I haven't looked into whether mypy will be able to perform exhaustiveness checking with that.